# How to run code at startup when not having access to application entry point

Tags: c#, backend, .net-4.8

We have a legacy (.net 4.8.x) backend application which is hosting remoting components in a Windows Service. Now I want to add a continuously running worker service which should start when application is started.

Normally this would be no problem to add but in our case the actual windows service (the .exe) is a generic windows service host application used for several applications. So that part is outide the solution. So I can't just add the startup code there. We have the code for host application though so can do changes to it.

One option is to change the host application that I add some options to configure startup code and use Reflection to instantiate the worker service class.

But is there any other options ? Like run code at assembly load in some way?

Comment: C#9 has Module initializers (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/module-initializers), though I'm not sure if they can be made to work with .net 4.8 (since that is officially unsupported) - according to the linked page there are third party injector libraries, so that is something you can search for

Comment: E.g.: a quick search suggests: https://github.com/fodyarchived/ModuleInit